# Why doesn't this generic exception handler in @ControllerAdvice get used?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want a "catch-all" method for any exception of type that inherits from `Exception`. When I try to inject multiple things, it's never called.

This does not get called:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception exception, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) throws Exception
{
    return null; //Temporary for testing
}
```

If I change to this, then it does get called:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception exception) throws Exception
{
    return null; //Temporary for testing
}
```

Why is that?

Shouldn't the annotation tell Spring Boot that it handles everything of type Exception?

The full class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class, RuntimeException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(HttpStatus status, WebRequest request, Exception exception) throws Exception
    {
        return null; //Put breakpoint here
    }

    /*@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception exception) throws Exception
    {
        return null;
    }*/
}
```

Comment: What if you remove only the `HttpStatus` parameter?

Comment: Add please a declaration of class

Comment: @DanyloZatorsky I added the full class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) `HttpStatus` is not part of allowed parameter types for `ExceptionHandler` methods:

> Handler methods which are annotated with this annotation are allowed
>   to have very flexible signatures. They may have parameters of the
>   following types, in arbitrary order:
>
> - An exception argument: declared as a general Exception or as a more specific exception. This also serves as a mapping hint if the
>     annotation itself does not narrow the exception types through its
>     value().
> - Request and/or response objects (typically from the Servlet API). You may choose any specific request/response type, e.g. ServletRequest
>     / HttpServletRequest.
> - Session object: typically HttpSession. An argument of this type will enforce the presence of a corresponding session. As a consequence,
>     such an argument will never be null. Note that session access may not
>     be thread-safe, in particular in a Servlet environment: Consider
>     switching the "synchronizeOnSession" flag to "true" if multiple
>     requests are allowed to access a session concurrently.
> - WebRequest or NativeWebRequest. Allows for generic request parameter access as well as request/session attribute access, without ties to
>     the native Servlet API.
> - Locale for the current request locale (determined by the most specific locale resolver available, i.e. the configured LocaleResolver
>     in a Servlet environment).
> - InputStream / Reader for access to the request's content. This will be the raw InputStream/Reader as exposed by the Servlet API.
> - OutputStream / Writer for generating the response's content. This will be the raw OutputStream/Writer as exposed by the Servlet API.
> - Model as an alternative to returning a model map from the handler method. Note that the provided model is not pre-populated with regular
>     model attributes and therefore always empty, as a convenience for
>     preparing the model for an exception-specific view.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer. Any idea why HttpStatus isn't part of that?

Comment: I think it is because the `HttpStatus` needs to be defined by you since you are the one who wants to provide custom logic as to how the exception will be handled. If you read Javadoc further it says that optionally you can annotate your method with `ResponseStatus` that allows you define how your exception maps to HttpStatus codes.